# Resharper keeps telling me my "ErrorMessageResourceName" is invalid

Tags: .net, resharper

I have a lot of properties like this:

```
 [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(ModelStrings), ErrorMessageResourceName = "RequiredValidationMessage")]
 public string MyProperty { get; set; }
```

`ModelStrings` is a Type generated automatically from my `ModelStrings.resx` which is in my `App_GlobalResources` directory. The code works perfectly in runtime.

However, Resharper shows an error in the string `RequiredValidationMessage` saying:

```
Cannot resolve symbol 'RequiredValidationMessage'
```

Any idea of how to solve it?

**Edit**

I'm using 7.1 final edition. I'm using resharper since 7.0 and this error always existed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the code compiles then it is a bug in Resharper.
Create a ticket in their bug tracker: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/RSRP
or just disable this error in the Resharper preferences.

Comment: I have submitted. Thanks for your reply